# Failing to install psycopg2-binary on new docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, psycopg2

I have encountered a problem while trying to run my django project on a new Docker container.
It is my first time using Docker and I can't seem to find a good way to run a django project on it. Having tried multiple tutorials, I always get the error about psycopg2 not being installed.

requirements.txt:

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
asgiref==3.2.7
django-cors-headers==3.3.0
django==3.0.7
djangorestframework==3.11.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
```

Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . .

# set project environment variables
# grab these via Python's os.environ
# these are 100% optional here

ENV PORT=8000
ENV SECRET_KEY_TWITTER = "***"
```

While running docker-compose build, I get the following error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source. Please add the directory

containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the

option:

python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI

'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
```

I will gladly answer any questions that might lead to the solution.
Also, maybe someone can recommend me a good tutorial on dockerizing django apps?

Comment: I think you need to have the PostgreSQL client installed before pip installing the package. EDIT: I actually had the same issue when using Py3.8 and i reverted back to Py3.7 and installed it without any issues.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On Alpine Linux, you will need to compile all packages, even if a pre-compiled binary wheel is available on PyPI. On standard Linux-based images, you won't (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/ - there are also other articles I've written there that might be helpful, e.g. on security).

So change your base image to `python:3.8.3-slim-buster` or `python:3.8-slim-buster` and it should work.

Comment: It actually solved my problem, even if partially, thanks! Unfortunately now I get the error when running the container, django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known . Gonna try to solve that one now.

Comment: If you're using Compose, make sure your database service name is `db`.

Comment: I am actually, I created a post about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729917/connecting-postgresql-db-to-django-project-using-docker

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error when using `python:3.8-slim-buster`.

Comment: Now try switching to installing `psycopg-binary`.

Answer (score 71):

I made it work. This is the code:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim #Image python:3.9.5-slim also works # Image python:3.9.5-slim-buster also works

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc \
    && pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: This won't work for `psycopg2`. But if you change to images `3.9.5-slim` or `3.9.5-slim-buster`, it will.

Comment: Sergio what are you mean it won't work? It is working now, my django project using this settings.

Comment: I did not make it work `psycog2` with version `3.8.3`. But I managed to do it with version `3.9.5`.

Comment: Doing it exactly this way worked for me. What did not work was installing it through the `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 12):

This scripts work on MacBook Air M1

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc && pip install psycopg2
COPY requirements.txt /cs_account/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt

```
psycopg2-binary~=2.8.6
```

Updated answer from the answer of Zoltán Buzás

Comment: Have you tried running the `GOARCH=amd64 docker build ....` ? Did you still need to install gcc if you specified GOARCH? I don't have an M1 mac, but I am trying to help another engineer with an M1 Mac. Thanks!  

Note: You'll need to have rosetta installed https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/

Comment: Yes, I still had to install libpq-dev and gcc.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. Try slim-buster image.

In your `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8.7-slim-buster
```

and in your `requirements.txt` file

```
psycopg2-binary~= <<version_number>>
```

Answer (score 3):

I added this to the top answer because I was getting other errors like below:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and

```
src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
#include <sql.h>
```

This is what I did to fix this, so I am not sure how others were getting that to work, however maybe it was some of the other things I was doing?

My solution that I found from other posts when googling those two errors:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim 

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y install g++ libpq-dev gcc unixodbc unixodbc-dev
```

Comment: Fixed it for me, `g++` seems to make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a custom image with

```
FROM python:alpine
ADD requirements.txt /
RUN apk update --no-cache \
&& apk add build-base postgresql-dev libpq --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
&& pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
&& pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt \
&& apk del .build-deps
RUN apk add postgresql-libs libpq --no-cache
```

and requirements.txt

```
django
djangorestframework
psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

To others that may have this problem - (I know OP doesn't have this issue) but it could be that you are attempting to install `psycopg2` instead of `psycopg2-binary` which was my problem.

Comment: Worth to note that there is a difference between psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary: [Link](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#psycopg-vs-psycopg-binary) - _For production use you are advised to use the source distribution._