# Connecting PostgreSQL db to Django project using Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have a problem connecting my Postgres database to django project on docker container.
I have already tried every solution found on the internet and nothing seems to work.
I've already added host all  all   all   md5 to my pg_hba.conf file, listen_addresses = '*' to postgresql.conf.
Here is log from lsof -i :5432:

```
postgres 19774 postgres    5u  IPv4 2046377      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 19774 postgres    6u  IPv6 2046378      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

I've tried to open 5432 port by using ufw allow 5432/tcp, it seems to be open.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    build: .
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
    ports:
      - '5432'

  web:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
    volumes:
      - ./TwitterClone/:/usr/src/TwitterClone/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
networks:
    djangonetwork:
      driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

settings.py:

```
try:
    DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
    DATABASE_USER = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER')
    DATABASE_NAME = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB')
except:
    print('Could not get environment variables')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,
        'USER': DATABASE_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

No matter what I try to do, I always end up getting that error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Thank you in advance for any help, anything could help. Just let me know if you need more information from me, I will gladly provide it.

**EDIT:**
I have edited my docker-compose file by deleting all networks related lines. Now I don't get the previous error, but it seems to have a problem with my PostgreSQL server running on port 5432:

```
ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint db (a1ed9a70eddb931e5d2a26522cb95a2873e019029420f8b994146e6bebe5ce09): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
```

Comment: What's the output from `docker ps`?

Comment: docker ps gives an empty output(only column names), docker ps -aq gives f8c81116b49c
c3fa23b7818e

Comment: Test 1. change your. `HOST': 'db', 'PORT': 5432,`

Comment: @abestrad it gives me an error: `ERROR: for e6f7490472bd_db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint db (476caa84ff10ca98ee1f59b946b98b4dfe02a018fab2e00fa6b8cf9bd0a2b195): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint db (476caa84ff10ca98ee1f59b946b98b4dfe02a018fab2e00fa6b8cf9bd0a2b195): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use`

Comment: Should I leave my Postgres server running while trying to run the containers?

Comment: It's not possible to share the same address (`0.0.0.0:5432`)  between two services . So, you have to stop one of the services using the address.

Comment: @abestrad i stopped postgres running in the background. Unfortunately now I get an error saying `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known` which I was getting a while ago actually.